# Javascript: Suma de montos en tiempo real

Tags: javascript, jquery

`introducir el código aquí`Tengo la siguiente funcion que funciona para sumar los montos en unos `inputs` que tengan la clase `monto_cierre`:

```
function sumamodal() {
// Para suma de montos de cierre
var total = 0;
    $(".monto_cierre").each(function () {
        var valorunp_v = $(this).val();
        valorunp_v = valorunp_v.replace(simbolo, '');
        valorunp_v = valorunp_v.replace(/\./g,'');
        valorunp_v = valorunp_v.replace(',', '.');
        valorunp_v = valorunp_v*100;
        valorunp_v = valorunp_v/100;
        valorunp_v = parseFloat(valorunp_v +0);

        if (isNaN(parseFloat(valorunp_v))) {
            total += 0;
        } else {
            total += parseFloat(valorunp_v);
        }
    });

    total = total*100;
    total_fixed = total.toFixed(2);
    total_fixed = parseFloat(total_fixed + 0);
    document.getElementById('total_cierre').value = total_fixed;
}
```

La mando a ejecutar de esta manera:

```
var intevalo = setInterval('sumamodal()',10);
```

Esto para que pueda hacer la suma de montos en tiempo real mientras se van ingresando en pantalla mostrando el total en un `input`. Sucede que he visto que el consumo de `memoria ram` en la pestaña donde se esta ejecutando esta funcion va aumentando progresivamente, hasta que llega el punto en que la pagina da error (Esto despues de un buen rato). 
La idea es si se puede optimizar este método y si existe algún otro para que los montos se vayan sumando en tiempo real.

Comment: como te dijeron, es mejor ejecutar la función ante un evento sobre los inputs. Respecto al consumo de memoria, un intervalo de 10 milisegundos probablemente es menor que lo que demora la función en ejecutarse, por lo cual se van encolando peticiones hasta colapsar el browser. Si usarar un intervalo de (por decir) 200ms, la diferencia sería imperceptible y el browser no colapsaría. Aún así, el método seguiría siendo subóptimo.

Comment: PD: ¿Qué sentido tienen todos esos reemplazos? Estás asumiendo que el número viene en formato ###.###,000 ? El símbolo es la moneda? Por qué multiplicas el total por 100?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fácil, sólo pasa un `keyup` a los selectores con clase `monto_cierre` e invoca la función. Te dejo un ejemplo trabajando.

No necesitas el `setInterval` ya que el `keyup` lo suma en tiempo real (Al teclazo)
PD. Quité la línea `valorunp_v = valorunp_v.replace(simbolo, '');` Por que no sé de donde sacas `simbolo`

```js
function sumamodal() {
// Para suma de montos de cierre
var total = 0;
    $(".monto_cierre").each(function () {
        var valorunp_v = $(this).val();
        valorunp_v = valorunp_v.replace(/\./g,'');
        valorunp_v = valorunp_v.replace(',', '.');
        valorunp_v = valorunp_v*100;
        valorunp_v = valorunp_v/100;
        valorunp_v = parseFloat(valorunp_v +0);

        if (isNaN(parseFloat(valorunp_v))) {
            total += 0;
        } else {
            total += parseFloat(valorunp_v);
        }
    });

    total = total*100;
    total_fixed = total.toFixed(2);
    total_fixed = parseFloat(total_fixed + 0);
   $('#total_cierre').val(total_fixed);
}

$(document).on('keyup','.monto_cierre',function(){
  sumamodal();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="monto_cierre"><br>
<input type="text" class="monto_cierre"><br>
<input type="text" class="monto_cierre"><br>
<input type="text" class="monto_cierre"><br>
<input type="text" id="total_cierre" readonly><br>
```

Answer (score 0):

Para hacer eso es mejor usar `addEventListener`, te pongo un ejemplo.

El HTML:

```
<!--Tus inputs ".monto_cierre"-->
<input type="number" class="monto_cierre" >
<input type="number" class="monto_cierre" >
<input type="number" class="monto_cierre" >
<input type="number" class="monto_cierre" >

<!-- El total -->
<input type="number" class="total_cierre" >
```

Ahora usaremos `javascrip` para añadir un evento `input` o `keyup`, usaré `keyup` para este ejemplo.

Aquí el Javascript:

```
//Usamos jQuery para seleccionar y recorrer cada uno de los elementos input con la clase `monto_cierre`
$('.monto_cierre').each(function(){
    //Añadimos el manejador del  evento, nótese que para añadir el manejador del evento estoy usando javascript puro, sin embargo también es posible usar jQuery
    //$(this).on('keyup', function(){});
    this.addEventListener('keyup', function(){
        //Aquí ejecuta la función 'sumamodal'
        sumamodal();
    }, false);
});
```

Ahora cada que se tecleé en alguno de los `input.monto_cierre`, tu función `sumamodal` se ejecutará, en vez de ejecutarse cada 10 milésimas de segundo.